# How to create the Apache Cordova App with a cloud Backend like news and info App?

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, apache-cordova

I'm trying to create a cloud backend to update news and info on my app please help me out with a documentation or guide me on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will all depend on the cloud back end you choose to use.  Visual Studio does have an integrated connected service experience for [Azure Mobile Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/mobile-services/)

Grab a free trial, right click on your project, select "Add > Connected Service..." and select Azure Mobile Service to add it in.